# keep Toolbar position fix in layout when soft keyboard comes and soft keyboard below edit text

Tags: android, android-layout

this is my simple view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main3"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.utkarsh.test.Main3Activity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="180dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:hint="edit text1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:hint="edit text2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:hint="edit text3" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:hint="edit text4" />


</LinearLayout>
```

I want 2 conditions: 
1] as soon as i start typing in my edit text the keyboard should be below that particular edit text 
2] the title bar should remain fix at that position .

I have used  **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** in manifest to achieve fist condition , but at same time 2 condition is not achieved .
secondly using   **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"** acheives 2 condition but 1 not acheived .
Using both  **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"** does same thing like adjust resize . I have tried all answers like **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"** but nothing helped

How can i achieve both conditions ??

Comment: can coordinator layout do some?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, try to use `ScrollView`. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="pl.com.qubuss.test.RegisterActivity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/nameET"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="@string/nameTextHint"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:width="200dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/surnameET"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nameET"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nameET"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/nameET"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:hint="@string/surnameTextHint" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/emailET"
    android:hint="@string/emailTextHint"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/surnameET"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/surnameET"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/surnameET"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/username_registerET"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailET"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/emailET"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/emailET"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:hint="@string/usernameTextHint" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/password_registerET"
    android:layout_below="@+id/username_registerET"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username_registerET"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/username_registerET"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="@string/passwordTextHint" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/registerButton"
    android:id="@+id/registerButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/conPasswor_registerET"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/conPasswor_registerET"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password_registerET"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password_registerET"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/password_registerET"
    android:hint="@string/conPasswordTextHint" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```